# How I can get web page's content and display it in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net

i am having trouble making a program that will search this web page for the latest news about the currency market.When i compile the programm the textbox is just empty and nothing happens. Can someone please help me out . Thanks

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
  using System.Net;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
        public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebClient x = new WebClient();
        string source = x.DownloadString("https://www.dailyfx.com/forex/video/live_events/2016/10/11/Strategy-Video-Opportunity-in-Reconvergence-of-USDCAD-and-Oil-Price-Correlation.html");
        //Get Title
        string title = Regex.Match(source, @"\<p\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</p\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["p"].Value;

        textBox1.Text =title;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using an improper group name - it's `Title`, rather than `p`, according to your regex. This yields "Market News Headlines" for me:

```
string title = Regex.Match(source, @"\<p\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</p\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;
```